# passing extra argumenets to devtools::build

Tags: r, package, devtools

Something seems to have changed in the `devtools`package, so that the following commands, that used to run now give an error I can't decipher:

```
> Sys.setenv(R_GSCMD="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.21/bin/gswin64c.exe")
> devtools::build(args = c('--resave-data','--compact-vignettes="gs+qpdf"'))
   The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Error in (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE,  : 
  System command error
```

I've tried other alternatives with other `devtools` commands, like just passing a single argument, but still get the same error

```
args = '--compact-vignettes="gs+qpdf"'
devtools::check_win_devel(args=args)
```

I'm using devtools 2.2.0, under R 3.5.2

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but is useful. You can also build inside R like this: `shell(paste0('R CMD build ', pkg_name, ' ', build_opt)`

Comment: Does it work if you build without devtools? E.g. `system("R CMD build . --resave-data ..."))` ? If yes, then please open a devtools issue at https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues

Comment: Haven't tried this yet, but a good test. I did open a devtools issue.

Comment: W/o `devtools` this works as expected: `system('R CMD build . --resave-data --compact-vignettes="gs+qpdf"')`